# Integrating DBpedia Lookup into Laravel 5+

Tags: scala, maven, laravel, dbpedia

Any idea how to integrate [DBpedia Lookup API](https://github.com/dbpedia/lookup) into a `Laravel` application?
I have a Form in `Laravel 5.1` and want to send the query to `DBpedia lookup API`, which is a maven project written in `Scala`, to search for my keyword and return the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `php curl` for communication between my `Laravel` app and `Scala API`, so I sent my query to the API and sent the results back to my View in Laravel where the form locates.

There are couple of custom libraries to do this in Laravel in my case I used  [ixudra/curl](https://github.com/ixudra/curl).